# storybook организация проекта

Tags: storybook

Возник вопрос. С самим Storybook в общих чертах все понятно. Но как это все взаимодействует с проектом?

Я создаю компоненты, пишу для них story, и все замечательно и хорошо. Я это должен в итоге использовать просто как набор компонентов, лежащих где-то которые я беру и копирую в проект? Но в этой истории есть проблема - получается две копии компонентов, которые могут независимо меняться.

Можно, конечно, извратиться и писать компоненты так, чтоб они работали и в storybook, и в проекте, но появляется тогда какой-то дополнительный код, который понимает, в какой среде он запущен. В общем, буду признателен, если кто - то поделится опытом. Такое впечатление что не хватает какого то кирпичика для понимания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Человечество изобрело другие способы повторного использования компонентов кроме копипаста.

Один из них - организовать вашу библиотеку с компонентами в отдельный npm package, к которому и прикрутить сторибук. При этом разумеется необязательно (и даже нежелательно) замусоривать npm registry - современные пакетные менеджеры поддерживают локальные зависимости. Проблема "нескольких источников правды" обычно решается именно так.

> Можно, конечно, извратиться и писать компоненты так, чтоб они работали и в storybook, и в проекте, но появляется тогда какой-то дополнительный код, который понимает, в какой среде он запущен.

Нужно.
Если у Вас компонент не работает и в сторибук и в проекте то он имеет какую-то неявную зависимость от проекта (или от сторибука). А неявные зависимости обычно чреваты отстреленными ногами.

Также это может быть очень проектоспецифичный компонент. Но тогда пусть останется в проекте, не надо тащить на общий стол все что сделяль.

Дополнительный код для компонента обычно писать не нужно (хотя способы для этого есть).
Что нужно - это возиться с конфигурацией. У сторибука свой конфиг вебпака, бабеля, тайпскрипта и черта лысого. И чтобы компоненты хотя бы работали в проектах и сторибуке, эти конфиги надо как-то дружить.

В итоге, разработка со сторибуком (и аналогами) - это практика для более-менее зрелых проектов с какими-то требованиями к надежности и общей кодовой базой. Если Вам нужен ультраскоростной хренак-хренак, то сторибук только мешаться будет.

Comment: Спасибо хоть кто то что-то пояснил, а то такое впечатление что что со story мало кто связывается.

Comment: Все равно вопросы не исчезли)). Создал я в story компоненты. Отражается их различное состояния. Но в реальном проекте где будут эти компоненты, они же будут вплетены в redux. route.и тд и по любому будут изменены, что нарушит их сходство с копиями в story. через npm эта проблема не решается. Установил я через npm компоненты из story. но в итоге я начну их привязывать к redux к обмену с сервером и эти компоненты будут кодом дополняться. И приехали. Ну изменю я что то в story  в npm а в проекте уже дописаны для компонентов связки. В общем то ли я дурак то ли лыжи не едут))

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов если вам надо костылить реализацию компонентов под каждый проект, то скорее всего у вас хреново задизайнен программный интерфейс компоненты и плохо с разделением ответственности

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов посмотрите любую библиотеку компонентов общего назначения вроде анта или материала. Вот в сторибуке обычно хранится ваша библиотека компонентов общего назначения. Вы же если надо закостылить чего-то в том же анте _обычно_ не лезете внутрь либы руками а пользуетесь инструментами предусмотренными разработчиками библиотеки.

Comment: Спасибо за наводки на мысли.Иногда какие-то мелочи добавляют более полную картину.